# Get name of a specific network interface in Java

Tags: java, jvm, network-programming, network-interface

I am using windows 10 and I would like to plug a device on my computer (which created a new network interface with the name "Ethernet 12" and description "foobar") and be able to set the IP address of this interface using Java. Using this link: [Change Computer IP address using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231227/change-computer-ip-address-using-java), I am able to configure the IP address of the interface. The issue I have is that I am not able, in java, to retrieve the name of the interface created by the device. From the documentation I found, I did the following:

```
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces =  NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

    while(networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements())
    {
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();

        if (networkInterface.isUp())
            System.out.println("Display name: " + networkInterface.getDisplayName() + "\nName: " + networkInterface.getName() + "\nAddress: " + networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0));
    }
```

and got the following result:

```
    Display name: foobar
    Name: eth15
    Address 111.116.15.4
```

I expected the name to be "Ethernet 12" and not "eth15", which doesn't seem to make any sense. I noticed the same for all my other interface (wifi, ethernet, etc...). Since I need the real name of my interface (Ethernet 12) to configure the IP address with netsh (and not a random one like "eth15"), I am stuck...

Is there a reason why I am getting "eth15" as the name of my interface ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you're not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803545/java-networkinterface-getname-broken-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a reason why I am getting "eth15" as the name of my interface ?

That took some digging. In Java world, `NetworkInterfaces` are enumerated by `java.net.NetworkInterface::getNetworkInterfaces()` which calls the **native** `java.net.NetworkInterface::getAll()`.

We can find the native source code for `getAll()` in OpenJDK 11 [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/NetworkInterface.c#L31) where we find this comment:

```
/*
 * Windows implementation of the java.net.NetworkInterface native methods.
 * This module provides the implementations of getAll, getByName, getByIndex,
 * and getByAddress.
 *
 * Interfaces and addresses are enumerated using the IP helper routines
 * GetIfTable, GetIfAddrTable resp. These routines are available on Windows
 * 98, NT SP+4, 2000, and XP. They are also available on Windows 95 if
 * IE is upgraded to 5.x.
 *
 * Windows does not have any standard for device names so we are forced
 * to use our own convention which is based on the normal Unix naming
 * convention ("lo" for the loopback, eth0, eth1, .. for ethernet devices,
 * tr0, tr1, .. for token ring, and so on). This convention gives us
 * consistency across multiple Windows editions and also consistency with
 * Solaris/Linux device names. Note that we always enumerate in index
 * order and this ensures consistent device number across invocations.
 */
```

So once upon a time, when Windows 95 was still a thing, someone decided not to read the actual Windows interface names, and instead use "our own convention". Why? No idea. I would have preferred getting a separate `deviceName()` and a `ourOwnConventionWhichHasNothingToDoWithTheActualNameDeviceName()`, but unfortunately I wasn't consulted.

The underlying Windows API call [GetIfTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getiftable) does return a name for each interface in the form an array of [MIB_IFROW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ifmib/ns-ifmib-mib_ifrow):

```
typedef struct _MIB_IFROW {
  WCHAR                   wszName[MAX_INTERFACE_NAME_LEN];
  IF_INDEX                dwIndex;
  IFTYPE                  dwType;
  DWORD                   dwMtu;
  DWORD                   dwSpeed;
  DWORD                   dwPhysAddrLen;
  UCHAR                   bPhysAddr[MAXLEN_PHYSADDR];
  DWORD                   dwAdminStatus;
  INTERNAL_IF_OPER_STATUS dwOperStatus;
  DWORD                   dwLastChange;
  DWORD                   dwInOctets;
  DWORD                   dwInUcastPkts;
  DWORD                   dwInNUcastPkts;
  DWORD                   dwInDiscards;
  DWORD                   dwInErrors;
  DWORD                   dwInUnknownProtos;
  DWORD                   dwOutOctets;
  DWORD                   dwOutUcastPkts;
  DWORD                   dwOutNUcastPkts;
  DWORD                   dwOutDiscards;
  DWORD                   dwOutErrors;
  DWORD                   dwOutQLen;
  DWORD                   dwDescrLen;
  UCHAR                   bDescr[MAXLEN_IFDESCR];
} MIB_IFROW, *PMIB_IFROW;
```

The JVM seems to [read this array](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/737d8437886ad97c6ed21a25b9911c10b3886f61/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/NetworkInterface.c#L188), then [generate an "appropriate" name](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/737d8437886ad97c6ed21a25b9911c10b3886f61/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/NetworkInterface.c#L226), and finally [override the OS-provided name with the generated one](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/737d8437886ad97c6ed21a25b9911c10b3886f61/src/java.base/windows/native/libnet/NetworkInterface.c#L278).

In short, it doesn't look like the implementation has changed in many years, and it's probably impossible to change at this point without creating a completely new API. Otherwise you risk breaking people's code.

The way I see it, there are two ways to get the actual interface names:

1. Use JNI to make the native call to `GetIfTable` yourself.
2. Execute `netsh` and parse the response.

Both solutions are kinda ugly and require you to make sure you're running on Windows.